# What Would This Sauerkraut Dish Be Called?

Tags: eggs, bacon, sauerkraut

I have a receipe I've been making for a while. I expect that it's "some kind of... or some variation of... " but have no idea what that might be.

*Ingredients*

- Thick Cut Bacon (100g?). I've been buying the whole bacon pieces from the deli and thick slicing (0.7cm?) across the short face.
- Saerkraut (1.5 cups)
- Grated chedder
- two eggs
- Sriracha to taste
- Fry the bacon well

*Method*

- Drain and add the Sauerkraut and grated cheese.
- Cook until all the liquid has boiled off and the cheese is well melted. I even overcook the cheese so that it starts to harden.
- Add eggs (before the cheese is finished). Either stir through if you're in a hurry or make wells in the mixture and crack eggs in, so as to serve with unbroken yokes.
- Serve with Sriracha to taste.

Can someone please enlighten me as to what this dish might be?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Did you invent the recipe?

Comment: Yes, in so far as that I just made it up. It's so simple though I expect that it's been done before, hence my question. It might be the national dish of Estonia for all I know.

Comment: You mean apart from „fried sauerkraut with molten cheese and eggs”? I think we can assume that your creation is not the long-lost local speciality of some obscure Eurasian corner of the world.

Comment: It's sort of like Sauerkraut Grostl, but that would have potatoes and no cheese (or sriracha (note that this comes from Thailand, so not likely in Europe)), and the eggs would be added fried on the top I think rather than mixed in.

Comment: lol. You mock @Stephie, but now that this recipe has been released to the world and, it would seem, I lay claim to being it's creator, my honoured position in history is a certain!

Comment: Ignoring procedure and Sriracha, wouldn't that be Sauerkraut Carbonara ;-) ? At least, if the egg stays liquid.

Comment: According to wiki, "Carbonara is an Italian pasta dish ... made with eggs, hard cheese, cured pork and black pepper. 
That kind of fits!! :-)

Comment: Gröstl pretty much by definition has some starch as a main ingredient (potatoes, noodles, or cut bread dumplings), and is fried until crusts are formed. This doesn't sound like that would happen here, so I wouldn't call it that. I could, however, definitely see this as the filling of a sauerkraut strudel. But I like the Carbonara analogy! ("Soodles"?)

Comment: cool. The cheese kind of crusts up. Perhaps I need to get more heat into it. I might try it on the weber. Thanks :-)